# Configure Stack Depth of Chained Queueable Jobs

Tags: queueable-apex

I was going through the documentation related to the new `AsyncOptions` class, and looks like this is still in BETA. I remember this feature was released in Summer 23 release.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_queueable_enhancements.htm&release=244&type=5

But in the Apex Developer Guide, I can see a dedicated section "Adding a Queueable Job with a Specified Stack Depth" with a detailed explanation and code samples, and it's not saying BETA.

Can anyone confirm whether this is still in testing mode? There are some really nice additions to queueable jobs, and we would like to add these features in our current jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the Stack Depth in Queueables was made Generally Available in Winter 24.

See the release notes: [Set the Maximum Depth of Chained Queueable Jobs (Generally Available)](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_queueable_enhancements_ga.htm&release=246&type=5)